# XSLT transformation - multiple input XML files

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, merge, concatenation

I have a following problem: I have several input XML files, and one of them contains links to the others.
That one looks like this:

```
<Envelope>
<Part File='file:SEQ014/DET3262874.9.0.xml' LinkType='REL' DocType='XCD' SubType='Call' Format='XML'/>
<Part File='file:SEQ014/DET3262874.9.1.xml' LinkType='REL' DocType='XCD' SubType='Call' Format='XML'/>
<Part File='file:SEQ014/DET3262874.9.2.xml' LinkType='REL' DocType='XCD' SubType='Call' Format='XML'/>
<Part File='file:SEQ014/DET3262874.9.3.xml' LinkType='REL' DocType='XCD' SubType='Call' Format='XML'/>
<Part File='file:SEQ014/DET3262874.9.4.xml' LinkType='REL' DocType='XCD' SubType='Call' Format='XML'/>
<Part File='file:SEQ014/DET3262874.9.5.xml' LinkType='REL' DocType='XCD' SubType='Charge' Format='XML'/>
<Part File='file:SEQ014/INV3262874.9.xml' LinkType='REL' DocType='INV' Format='XML'/>
<Part File='file:SEQ014/INVINFO3262874.9.xml' LinkType='REL' DocType='IIN' Format='XML'/>
<Part File='file:SEQ014/SUM3262874.9.xml' LinkType='REL' DocType='SUM' Format='XML'/>
<Part File='file:SEQ014/BAL3262874.9.xml' LinkType='REL' DocType='BAL' Format='XML'/>
<Part File='file:SEQ014/ADDR3262874.9.xml' LinkType='REL' DocType='ADD' Format='XML'/>
</Envelope>
```

Now, I am accessing the files in the bottom like this:

```
<xsl:param name="BillingDocument2" select="/Bill/Part[@DocType='ADD']/@File"/>
<xsl:param name="BillingDocument3" select="/Bill/Part[@DocType='INV']/@File"/>
etc...
```

After that, I'm referencing them like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="var13_Document" select="document($BillingDocument2)/Document"/>
etc...
```

However, I do not know **how to use data from the first 5 XML files**? All those files have the same structure, and basically, it is one big file, split into 5 smaller ones...
I need to have all data from those 5 files (their number will vary from case to case) in one place, so I can process it in the same manner...
**Oh yeah, I can only use XSLT1!**

Answer (score 0):

The answer is basically in the same way that you're accessing the others.  If you say

```
<xsl:param name="XCDDocs" select="/Bill/Part[@DocType='XCD']/@File"/>
```

then this will give you a variable whose value is a set of 5 nodes (the `File` attribute node from each of the five `Part` elements in question).  Now when you pass a node set to the `document` function you get back another node set, consisting of the root nodes from the document whose URI is given by the string value of each node in the original set.  Thus

```
document($XCDDocs)/Document
```

is a set of five nodes, the `Document` element of each of the five files, and

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document($XCDDocs)/Document/*" />
```

would apply templates for all the first-level child elements of the document element in all five files, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, this is the first thing I've tried, and it did not work - as if it didn't get any of the DET files...
This is how I'm accessing it later:
`code`<xsl:variable name="var3829_Document" select="document($BillingDocument5)/Document"/>`code`
I guess I need some for-each loop?

Comment: @cameron And that definitely matches the format of the XML in the DET files - they have a root element named `Document` with no namespace?

Comment: Hi, still cannot make it to work:
This is how it is now
<xsl:for-each select="$var3829_Document/CallDetails/Call">
             <xsl:variable name="var3879_ORV" select="XCD/@ORV"/>          <xsl:if test="string(boolean($var3879_ORV)) != 'false'">           <xsl:variable name="var3880_resultof_total_roaming_gprs_broj">
               <xsl:call-template name="total_roaming_gprs_broj">
                <xsl:with-param name="broj" select="$var3879_ORV"/>             <xsl:with-param name="v_id" select="$var3828_Id"/>            </xsl:call-template>            </xsl:variable>

Any tips?

Comment: @cameron looking again at your example XML in the question, you say you're using XPaths like `/Bill/Part[....]` but your example XML has `Envelope` as its document element so they should be `/Envelope/Part[...]`.  Is this the case in your real XML too, or just in the version you posted here?

Comment: Managed to get it working, finally! :)
I used dynamic name generation...
Thank you for your help!